# Missing ) after argument list Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some Google Script that I'm using to be able to copy all the rows of a sheet called "Sheet2" in a certain order in a destination sheet called "Invitations en cours".

In the first column of sheet 2 is a panel code which I'm retrieving to be able to know where exactly I'm supposed to copy the row to, in the destination sheet which also contains, once, each panel code.

Basically I'm passing through all the rows in Sheet2 and copying all the non-empty ones to "Invitations en cours" under the right panel code which is found in its first column.

I have 2 questions:
1) How can I make sure to create a new row in Invitations en cours and not overriding what was already there? I wasn't able to find the right function for it.
2) Why does it say missing ) argument line 54? I can't find what I did wrong here.

```
//We get the range we want to eventually copy
var rowRange = sheet.getRange("A"+i:"Z"+i);
```

Thanks a lot for your help, please bear with me, it's my first time coding!

```
function onOpen() {
//Adding menu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Fonctions spéciales')
      .addItem('Copier range', 'CopyRange')
      .addToUi();
}

function CopyRange() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = source.getLastRow();
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var i = 2;
  var r = i;
  var cell = source.getActiveCell();
  var sheetDestination = source.getSheetByName("Invitations en cours");
  var range = sheetDestination.getRange("A"+r);
  var cellFind = range.getCell(r, "A");
  var value = cellFind.getValue();
  //finding the right panel codes in the first column of the destination sheet
  for (r; r < lastRow; r++) {
    switch(value) {
      case "co":
        var confCo = cellFind;
        break;
      case "ca":
        var confCa = cellFind;
        break;
      case "1":
        var panelUn = cellFind;
        break;
      case "2":
        var panelDeux = cellFind;
        break;
      case "3":
        var panelTrois = cellFind;
        break;
      case "4":
        var panelQuatre = cellFind;
        break;
      case "5":
        var panelCinq = cellFind;
        break;
      case "6":
        var panelSix = cellFind;
        break;
    }
    }
  //Copying each row to the destination sheet under the right panel code
   while (i <= lastRow) {
     i++
     //We get the range we want to eventually copy
     var rowRange = sheet.getRange("A"+i:"Z"+i);
     //We check for blanks
     if (sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue()!=="") {
       //We create a row under the panel codes we looked for earlier
       switch("A"+i.getValue()) {
          case "co":
            rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, confCo.getColumn(), confCo.getColumn());
            break;
          case "ca":
            rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, confCa.getColumn(), confCa.getColumn());
            break;
          case "AM1":
           rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, panelUn.getColumn(), panelUn.getColumn());
           break;
          case "AM2":
           rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, panelDeux.getColumn(), panelDeux.getColumn());
           break;
          case "AM3":
           rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, panelTrois.getColumn(), panelTrois.getColumn());
           break;
          case "PM1":
           rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, panelQuatre.getColumn(), panelQuatre.getColumn());
           break;
          case "PM2":
           rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, panelCinq.getColumn(), panelCinq.getColumn());
           break;
          case "PM3":
           rowRange.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestination, 2, 26, panelSix.getColumn(), panelSix.getColumn());
           break;
         default:`enter code here`
           text = "Je ne trouve pas un des codes panels suivants : co, ca, AM1, AM2, AM3, PM1, PM2, PM3. Avez-vous copié les codes panels?";
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon here: `i++`

Comment: I corrected my problems and I changed the code a lot since I didn't plan well enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have an issue with string concatenation.

```
sheet.getRange("A"+i:"Z"+i);
```

should be

```
sheet.getRange("A"+i + ":Z"+i);
```